# Python script running in IDLE but not in terminal

Tags: python, mqtt, gpio

There are many instances of this problem here, but all of them list an error when attempting to run the script.  When I try to run my script from the terminal, it thinks for about a second, then just goes back to a normal terminal prompt (without an error message).

I am new to Python, so forgive me if I'm simply doing something wrong, but for the life of me . . . this runs perfectly fine when opening/running in IDLE.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
import paho.mqtt.publish as publish
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

RELAY_PIN_1 = 23
RELAY_PIN_2 = 24

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(RELAY_PIN_1, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.setup(RELAY_PIN_2, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.HIGH)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    client.subscribe("/amber/1/1")
    client.subscribe("/amber/1/2")

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    if msg.topic == "/amber/1/1":
        if msg.payload == b'ON':
            GPIO.output(RELAY_PIN_1, GPIO.LOW)
        elif msg.payload == b'OFF':
            GPIO.output(RELAY_PIN_1, GPIO.HIGH)

    if msg.topic == "/amber/1/2":
        if msg.payload == b'ON':
            GPIO.output(RELAY_PIN_2, GPIO.LOW)
        elif msg.payload == b'OFF':
            GPIO.output(RELAY_PIN_2, GPIO.HIGH)

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect("10.0.0.163", 1883, 60)

client.loop_start()
```

In case anyone is wondering, I have been trying to run this using the command `python mqtt.py` (with `mqtt.py` being the file name). Also, I am using Python2.7 in both IDLE and from the terminal.

Comment: If it thinks about it for a second then goes back to the prompt without error that normally means it's run to completion.

Comment: That's one thought I had, but the `client.loop_start` line should keep it going until canceled . . . or at least I thought it should.  Either way, it continues to run and listen for MQTT posts when running from IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `loop_start()` you start the client on another thread, but right after that the script ends and the process terminates and so nothing happens.

If you want the client to keep running, either `sleep()` in your main thread after `loop_start()`, or instead, call `loop_forever()`, which will loop in the current thread and so your script will not terminate.

See the **network loop** section in the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.1#network-loop).

Comment: That was it.  Thank you!  I knew it had to be something simple.  The tutorial I was working with showed nothing about calling `loop_forever()`.  Just goes to show I should read the documentation closer.